# Binary Search Array VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net

When I used this in my program is gives me "No value found" But the array strGenre contains "Rock" I don't understand why it's giving a negative value.

```
Dim intValue As Integer

    intValue = Array.BinarySearch(strGenre, "Rock")

    If intValue > 0 Then
        lstPlayList.Items.Add(strSongs(intValue))
    Else
        MsgBox("No value found", , "Error")
    End If
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct character casing? I.e. `"rock"` and `"Rock"` would not be the same as far as I know.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes I made sure of that. The array also holds pop, rap, and R&B and they all have capital letters in the beginning of the word

Comment: You don't show how you've defined the `strGenre` array.

Comment: Maybe Rock is the first item of your list and it has an index of 0. You should dump the str/int from your variable, it makes it very confusing since it looks like strGenre is a string, not an array.

Comment: Could you give us the type of `strGenre` ? Also, as @the_lotus pointed out, if `Rock` is the first item in your array, you end up with `intValue = 0`, therefore you will believe it is not found...

Comment: @SuperPeanut i'm defining it like this `Private strGenre(53) As String` and I've tried replacing "Rock" with "Pop" and it's still going to the else statement

Comment: For some odd reason "Rap" and "R&B" work but nothing else

Comment: Did you sort the array first as is required? [Array.BinarySearch - Remarks Section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: @TnTinMn um.... no but now when I do that it gets all mixed up

Comment: I don't know what you mean by: " it gets all mixed up", but you could also use the `Contains` function to determine if the value is in the array.

Comment: @TnTinMn so the code above is executed when the user selects a genre from the combo box. When the user selects "Rock" it should display "All You Need is Love-Beatles" (in general it doesn't do that but for the sake of the example is does) When I sort the array it displays "Touch it-Busta Rhymes" which is not a rock song. These songs and genres are coming from a single text file and then processed into three arrays called songs genre and length, if you were wondering.

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that this is homework assignment and you have been instructed to use three arrays?

Comment: Homework/Project yes

Comment: @demonkiller3418, If you must use 3 arrays in parallel, it is a a bit clumsy and is done by sorting all arrays against the same original key values.  Look at the documentation for the Sort method overload that takes an array of key values.  This discussion is  going astray of the original problem and has become one of program design.  Give my sugestion a try and post a new question if you still have problems.